# Use multi language dictionary with aspell

Tags: dictionary, aspell

I have a large .tex file that contains two languages and I want to spellcheck it without going crazy. So just spellchecking for one language and pressing "ignore" for words from the other language is not an option.

So I read up on aspell and found out you can define your own `.multi` files to combine dictionaries. But apparently you can't do this for dictionaries from different languages, it throws an error (or, if you're working from a GUI, the dictionary will just appear empty).

Also, I found a bug report putting this feature on the wishlist, but it seems no one has implemented it yet.

So, my question is: Are there any sane ways of using two dictionaries for two different languages at once?

This problem gave me a headache and there's next to no documentation on how to do it on the internet. So, I'll put up the workaround I found as an answer, to save anyone else (including future me) the trouble. 
But if you have a better solution, please post it.

Answer (score 3):

So, here's my how-to:

Step 1: Find your aspell dictionaries on your system. I found them in `/usr/lib/aspell/`. You will see `.multi` and `.rws` files. All the following commands are to be executed in that directory.

Step 2: Generate wordlists from the dictionaries you want. If the dictionaries have affixes stored with the words, you need to expand them.

```
aspell --lang=en --master=en.multi  dump master > /home/user/meinwoerterbuch.txt
aspell -d de dump master | aspell -l de expand | perl -e 'while(<>){ print join("\n", split), "\n";}' >> /home/user/meinwoerterbuch.txt
```

Here the German dictionary had to be expanded, and because I wanted one word per line, I used perl to take several words per line and print each of them on an extra line. Just look at the output of aspell (I recommend `head`) to see if you need to expand your dictionary or not.

Step 3: Choose a language name for your dictionary. I chose Hungarian, because I'm pretty sure I'm never going to actually use a Hungarian dictionary for spellchecking, and that way it will be easy to find. I think it has to be something with a valid ISO language code. For Hungarian, that's `hu`.

Step 4: Create `hu.dat` and `hu_phonet.dat` files. The most stripped down versions that seem to work are:

`hu.dat`:

```
name hu 
charset iso8859-1
soundslike hu
```

`hu_phonet.dat`:

```
version 0.1-2002.12.15-3
```

Step 5: Create your merged dictionary with

```
sudo aspell --lang=hu --encoding=utf-8 create master ./hu.rws < /home/user/meinwoerterbuch.txt
```

I had to put the encoding=utf-8, because the txt file is utf-8 encoded. It threw errors without it.

Step 6: Create an appropriate `hu.multi` file like this:

```
add hu.rws
```

Step 7: Choose Hungarian in your spellchecker and start spellchecking.